# Creating class object inside same class in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm trying to create a class object inside the class itself, something like this:

```
 class Motor:
 
 #other code here

     def function(self):
            x = Motor()
```

This works and runs correctly, but if I use inheritance to create another class as a daughter of this one (e.g. Car(Motor)), the Car.function() doesn't work properly because it's creating an object of type Motor, not Car. Is there any other way I could do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Not related to the problem at hand, but a car is not a kind of motor, so `Car` should not inherit from `Motor`.

Comment: @chepner that depends on dialect.  People in some areas of the UK would refer to a car as a 'motor', presumably as short for 'motor car'.

Comment: Even in that case, aren't "car" and "motor" synonymous, rather than one being a kind of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to receive the class to instantiate as an argument to the method, rather than hard-coding the class name.

```
class Motor:
    @classmethod
    def function(cls):
        x = cls()
        ...
```

If this is really something that needs to be an instance method, you can use `type(self)` instead.

```
class Motor:
    def function(self):
        x = type(self)()
```